# links wont work after multiple jquery load

Tags: jquery, load

im loading files inside two divs at the same time: #ajax_id and #ajax_col, the problem is when i make another link from inside one of the loaded divs, other links wont work anymore... this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var api = $('#ajax_in').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
   $('.aj4x').bind('click', function() {
      var action = $(this).attr("rel");
      api.getContentPane().load("ajax.php?id=" + action,
      function() {
        api.reinitialise();
        return false;
      });

      $("#ajax_col").load("ajax.php?col=" + action,function() { return false; });
   });
});
```

and this is how im making the links:

```
$('.bt').click(function() {
   $("#ajax_in").load("ajax.php?id=form123", function() { return false; });
});
```

after i click on a .bt, the content is loaded in the #ajax_in but the rest of the links dont work anymore (only the ones that load #ajax_col)

what im doing wrong? i can make it work when i change for live('click') but i read that the click function is already 'live'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.bind` to `.live` if your `.aj4x` links stop working.

If you `.bt` links stop working then change the

`$('.bt').click(` to `$('.bt').bind('click',`

The point is that you bring in new links, and the event handling has not been assigned to them.

The use of [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) allows for this

> **Description**: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match
>   the current selector, now and in the
>   future.

---

In answer to your addition about click being live. No click events assigned with `.click(..)` or `.bind('click',..)` are not live. They get assigned when the `.click` or `.bind` method is called only to the elements that match the selector at that time. Newly created elements will not have the handler, and thus the need for the `.live()` method.